# Create an array of array with HTML input

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I want to create a dynamic form to create users, with a "Add user" button that creates new inputs for another user.

```js
$('#add-user').click(function() {
  $(this).before(
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Username">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Email">' +
    '<br>'
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
  <br>
  
  <button type="button" id="add-user">Add user</button>
  <button type="submit">Create users</button>
</form>
```

I want the form data structured this way server-side (I am using PHP with Laravel):

```
$users = [
    [
        'username' => 'toto',
        'email'    => 'toto@email.fr',
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'titi',
        'email'    => 'titi@email.fr',
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'tata',
        'email'    => 'tata@email.fr',
    ]
]
```

I can't work out how I should name my inputs in order to do that. I know I must use the array names like this `name="user[]"`, but I am stuck.

Comment: you didn't specified a programming language, are you trying it on JS or PHP?

Comment: I am using PHP with Laravel. But my problem is client-side in HTML. What value must I give to the `name` attribute of my inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you need to make them like `name="user[]"`. I've made the small changes to your example below:

```js
$('#add-user').click(function() {
  $(this).before(
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username[]">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email[]">' +
    '<br>'
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username[]">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email[]">
  <br>
  
  <button type="button" id="add-user">Add user</button>
  <button type="submit">Create users</button>
</form>
```

Server side it will look like this:

```
Username [ 0 => "user1", 1 => "user2", ... ]
Email [ 0 => "email1", 1 => "email2", ... ]
```

Which you can easily transform into the format you want if you really need that.

Comment: I hadn't thought about transforming the format afterward. The problem is I am using Laravel validation but I found how to transform the request. I will do this way, thanks!